# Overriden method, that is invoked from parent constructor, doesn't initialize a field

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem:

```js
class A {
    value;

    constructor() {
        this.setUp();
    }

    setUp() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    value2;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        this.setUp2();
    }

    setUp2() {
        this.value2 = 5;
        console.log(this.value2); //    However, the value was assigned here. 
    }
}

let b = new B();
console.log(b.value);
console.log(b.value2); // But here value2 field is undefined.
```

I noticed, that if turn on ES2015, value2 is also displayed, but in my browser and application doesn't (I use ES6). Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons that it's generally not a good idea to call overrideable methods from constructors, exactly this kind of interaction is problematic.

The issue isn't that `value2` doesn't get set (as you've shown with your `console.log`, it does). The problem is that that value gets **overwritten** with `undefined` because of the public field declaration. Your

```
value2;
```

declaration in the `class` construct is functionally equivalent to:

```
value2 = undefined;
```

That initialization is processed immediately after the call to `super` in `B`'s constructor, overwriting the value `setUp2` put there *during* the `super` call.

The solution is not to call overrideable methods from constructors. :-) Instead, do your setup in the constructor, or in a [private method](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) (if your environment supports them), or in a utility function you use from the constructor (if you need this logic in multiple places in the class).

So, the simple way is to use initializers:

```js
class A {
    value = 1;
}

class B extends A {
    value2 = 5;
}

let b = new B();
console.log(b.value);  // 1
console.log(b.value2); // 5
```

...or put that initialization logic in the constructor explicitly, which is what constructors are for:

```js
class A {
    value;

    constructor() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    value2;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.value2 = 5;
    }
}

let b = new B();
console.log(b.value);  // 1
console.log(b.value2); // 5
```

But if you need that logic in a function because you use it elsewhere, here's an example of making `setUp` a private method in each class (again, this assumes you need that functionality in a method because you're going to use it outside the constructor as well as inside):

```js
// >>>>> THIS ONLY WORKS IN ENVIRONMENTS WITH PRIVATE METHODS
//       (such as recent versions of Chromium, Chrome, and Brave)

class A {
    value;

    constructor() {
        this.#setUp();
    }

    #setUp() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    value2;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.#setUp();
    }

    #setUp() {
        this.value2 = 5;
    }
}

let b = new B();
console.log(b.value);  // 1
console.log(b.value2); // 5
```

If you also need to expose `setUp` as a public method, you can do that by having it call the private version. Only call the private one from the constructor, though:

```js
// >>>>> THIS ONLY WORKS IN ENVIRONMENTS WITH PRIVATE METHODS
//       (such as recent versions of Chromium, Chrome, and Brave)

class A {
    value;

    constructor() {
        this.#internalSetUp();
    }

    setUp() {
        this.#internalSetUp();
    }

    #internalSetUp() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    value2;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.#internalSetUp();
    }

    setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        this.#internalSetUp();
    }

    #internalSetUp() {
        this.value2 = 5;
    }
}

let b = new B();
console.log(b.value);  // 1
console.log(b.value2); // 5
```

Comment: I encountered with the problem, I need to override either constructor or method from constructor to initialize field and if it's possible add new fields. Some fields must to initialize before anothers via invoking child methods also. But everything depends on the fact that the constructor is impossible to override, maybe there is the pattern to solve it?

Comment: @etozhekim - There's no problem adding new fields, provided you use initializers or initialization code in the constructor to initialize them. There shouldn't be an order problem between superclass fields and subclass fields, the superclass fields are **always** initialized before the subclass fields, that's the nature of the relationship. There's also no problem overriding methods, provided you don't call those methods from the constructor. I'm not sure what problem you're asking for a pattern for...?

Comment: @etozhekim - But I've added a fourth example at the end which *might* be what you're asking about. If not, though, just let me know and give me some details, I'll be glad to try to help further. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm going to try using private methods. Can I write you a detailed message later, if it won't help me? Because I spend whole day on this problem.

Comment: @etozhekim - Sure, or post a question with your [mre] of the problem and then ping me to let me know you've posted it. Then even if I'm not around, someone else may be able to help. Happy coding!